Gerrit rights for cloning a repo without a master branch (only tags exists)
I'm cloning a Github project which I'm then pushing to Gerrit for local development. I'd like to only push tags which I'm doing like this:
git push gerrit-remote --tags
The resulting repo in Gerrit has the contents I need at this stage.
However, in order to be able to clone the repo, it seems I need to add "read" rights to refs/*, which is not our default. Without this, I'll get "you appear to have cloned an empty repository" message from Git when I clone like this:
git clone ssh://user@gerrit-domain:port/repo-name
If I push the master branch as well as all the tags:
git push gerrit-remote master
..., everything works and I can clone without this extra rights (same command as above).
In the clone of the Github repo the "refs" dir only contains "heads" and "tags". Can someone explain or point me in the right direction? Thanks.
Here's a takeout of the Gerrit rights. I'm in groups Developers, BranchCreators and DirectPushers:
[access "refs/*"]
        read = group Administrators
        toggleWipState = group Developers
        toggleWipState = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        revert = group Registered Users
        pushMerge = group DirectPushers
[access "refs/heads/*"]
        create = group DirectPushers
        forgeAuthor = group Developers
        forgeAuthor = group DirectPushers
        forgeAuthor = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Developers
        label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group PrivilegedDevelopers
        push = group DirectPushers
        push = +force group ProjectAdmins
        submit = group Developers
        submit = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        label-Verified = -1..+1 group CI-Servers
        label-Verified = -1..+1 group Developers
        label-Verified = -1..+1 group PrivilegedDevelopers
        read = group Anonymous Users
        read = group CI-Servers
        read = group Developers
        read = group DirectPushers
        read = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        read = group ReadOnlyAccess
        pushMerge = group DirectPushers
        removeReviewer = group Developers
        removeReviewer = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        forgeCommitter = group DirectPushers
[access "refs/meta/config"]
        exclusiveGroupPermissions = read
        create = group Administrators
        label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group Administrators
        push = group Administrators
        read = group Administrators
        read = group ReadOnlyAccess
        submit = group Administrators
        label-Verified = -1..+1 group Administrators
[access "refs/tags/*"]
        createTag = group CI-Servers
        createTag = group Developers
        createTag = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        push = group CI-Servers
        push = group Developers
        push = group DirectPushers
        push = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        push = +force group ProjectAdmins
        forgeCommitter = group CI-Servers
        forgeCommitter = group DirectPushers
        create = group DirectPushers
        forgeAuthor = group DirectPushers
[access "refs/tags/team_continuous/*"]
        createTag = group Administrators
        createTag = group CI-Servers
        push = +force group CI-Servers
        delete = group Administrators
        delete = group CI-Servers
[access "refs/for/refs/heads/*"]
        forgeCommitter = group DirectPushers
        push = group Developers
        push = group DirectPushers
        push = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        pushMerge = group Developers
        pushMerge = group DirectPushers
        pushMerge = group PrivilegedDevelopers
[access "refs/for/*"]
        addPatchSet = group Developers
        addPatchSet = group PrivilegedDevelopers
[access "refs/heads/wip/*"]
        create = group Developers
        create = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        push = +force group Developers
        push = +force group PrivilegedDevelopers
        delete = group CI-Servers
        delete = group Developers
        delete = group PrivilegedDevelopers
        forgeCommitter = group BranchCreators
        forgeAuthor = group BranchCreators
[access "refs/heads/release/*"]
        create = group BranchCreators
        forgeAuthor = group BranchCreators
        forgeCommitter = group BranchCreators
        push = group BranchCreators
[access "refs/heads/feature/*"]
        create = group BranchCreators
        forgeAuthor = group BranchCreators
        forgeCommitter = group BranchCreators
        push = group BranchCreators
        delete = group BranchDeleters

